# Windows storage for windows 8 app

Tags: windows-8

I used to develop wp7 apps using isolated storage. now i would like to port some apps to windows 8 and i want to used windows local storage to save some stuffs. For wp7, i use a common isolated storage settings but i dont know how to change its code into windows storage. 
I want to change the following codes to Windows.Storage -

```
if (!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue(
this.name, out this.value)) //**Need to change this codes for windows storage**
{
    this.value = this.defaultValue;
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[this.name] = this.value; //**Need to change this codes for windows storage**
}
```

Thank in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Good sample how to save\get\check application settings in windows 8 apps https://stackoverflow.com/a/14662969/1200453